# How to make ansible_facts available for roles in a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I wrote an ansible playbook to manage some hosts with Ansible 9. These hosts can be Debian or RedHat based.
A role in this playbook uses `ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_file_variety']` to do it's tasks according to the distro.

When I run my playbook i get the following error:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was:
  'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_distribution_file_variety'.
```

The following command quickly reveals that 'ansible_distribution_file_variety' does indeed exist:

`ansible -m setup -i ./inventory myhost | sed 's#.*SUCCESS =>##' | jq .ansible_facts.ansible_distribution_file_variety`

<s>It seems that `ansible_facts` does not reach the role. How can I make `ansible_facts` available to the role I am using?</s>

Currently I am testing this on a RedHat host:
The suggested debug statements confirm that `ansible_facts` don't seem to reach the role. What baffles me though is that only the Ubuntu task throws the error, while on the appropriate task-include it does not.
While the debug shows no value for both.

- playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Configure my hosts
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - default.config.yml
  roles:
    - role: myrole
```

- role **myrole**

```yaml
---
- name: Debug ansible facts
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Directory {{ ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_file_variety'] }}"

- name: Install CA cert for RedHat 9 systems
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: RedHat.yml
  when:
    - ansible_facts['distribution'] == 'RedHat'
    - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == '9'

- name: Install CA cert for Ubuntu systems
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: Ubuntu.yml
  when:
    - ansible_facts['ansible_distribution'] == 'Ubuntu'
    - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == '22'
```

Comment: Start by positionning a default i.e. `msg: "Directory {{ ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_file_variety'] | d('novalue') }}"` then understand where it exists and where it does not. Not all facts exist on every distributions.

Comment: ^— or debug the whole `ansible_facts` dictionary. The setup module, when run as an ad-hoc command or in a playbook could be misleading sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Discovering variables: facts and magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#discovering-variables-facts-and-magic-variables):

> You can access this data in the ansible_facts variable. By default, you can also access some Ansible facts as top-level variables with the `ansible_` prefix. You can disable this behavior using the `INJECT_FACTS_AS_VARS` setting.

So, based on that (and on the examples given in that document), you're supposed to use either `ansible_facts['distribution']`, or `ansible_distribution` - not `ansible_facts['ansible_distribution']`.

The same is shown in [Conditionals based on ansible_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts).

Also, check your `INJECT_FACTS_AS_VARS` setting to make sure the variables with `ansible_` prefix are available on top level.

> The suggested debug statements confirm that `ansible_facts` don't seem to reach the role

I'm not sure if you meant exactly this because it is possible only in one case - when facts gathering is disabled. You might want to check your `ansible.cfg` config or environment variables on the controller. Moreover, based on your role code, you're trying to debug only one key, not the whole
`ansible_facts` dictionary.

Besides, [as Zeitunator already mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78194028/how-to-make-ansible-facts-available-for-roles-in-a-playbook#comment137855883_78194028), some facts may be unavailable on some systems. So you can either use a more common fact (which I would recommend - see the links above for examples), or adjust your logic and explicitly check if the fact you're trying to rely on really exists using `is defined` test like this:

```yaml
- name: Install CA cert for RedHat 9 systems
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: RedHat.yml
  when:
    - ansible_distribution_file_variety is defined
    - ansible_distribution_file_variety == 'RedHat'
```

Side note: you named your task "... on Ubuntu systems" but you're checking for the exact OS version. I'd recommend to move this check inside the included task in case there are real differences - so that during the maintenance you'll change only one file and the logic is more clear. Same for RHEL (but at least the condition there matches the name).